# Why do some webpages use a little HTML, but so much JavaScript

Tags: frontend

Why do some webpages use a little HTML, but so much JavaScript? Someone even used JavaScript to append the HTML like: `<div> <span>` and so on; the HTML source code was hidden in JavaScript.

Like this:

[image: like this]

Comment: It all depends on how the developer wants to run their website.

Answer (score 0):

The modern web is growing greatly in terms of complexity and user expectations.

Users want more complex, rich content, delivered faster. JavaScript provides the capability to enable meeting this demand.

HTML by definition, (HyperText Markup Language) provides zero functionality to a website. It simply displays stuff. And CSS (Cascading Style Sheets), in particular CSS3, provides a minimal level functionality (like `import` -ing a font for example, or making a div spin or fade in and out)

For anything and everything else, you gotta use JavaScript. From controlling HTML, CSS, retrieving data from APIs (Application Progamming Interface) and handling user input, JavaScript does it all.